# Creating a WCF Service Inside a DNN Module

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dotnetnuke

Is It possible to expose data/functionality of a DNN module using WCF? 
I have created a WCF Service inside a DNN module and installed the module on my DNN instance. How should I access my WCF service?
Please note that I am using DNN 7

```
DNN instance : http://localhost/dnndev
Module Name : FirstDnnMod
```

Comment: I haven't used DNN in 5 years (back when it was version 4.x), but I would imagine it's no different than any other serf-hosted WCF service.  Simply instantiate the `ServiceHost` in your module and give it an endpoint URI.

Answer (score 0):

IWEB allows you to create Web Services for your DotNetNuke Portal. You simply upload the module and start adding your own methods.

http://iwebcf.codeplex.com/

http://iweb.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the routing functionality in DNN7, I've got a blog post for how to get SignalR working

http://www.chrishammond.com/blog/itemid/2624/using-signalr-with-dotnetnuke-modules.aspx